# How to add relative zoom to ZoomGestureHandler in python

Tags: python, gesture, pinchzoom

I am currently working on implementing a custom zoom gesture in Python for my mobile graphics library. Despite trying multiple solutions, including exploring ChatGPT, I encountered an issue with the code not functioning correctly.

The problem arises when I perform a pinch and zoom in, release, and attempt to zoom in again. Instead of continuing to zoom in, the zoom resets, which is not the intended behavior.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance from the community in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import sys
import sdl2
import sdl2.ext
import numpy as np
import math as ml
from spectrax import operations as op

class ZoomGestureHandler:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.zoom_level = 1.0
        self.zoom_factor = 0.01
        self.max_zoom = 2.0
        self.min_zoom = 0.5
        self.window = window
        self.finger_positions = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        self.finger_positions_pre = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
        self.finger_count = 0
        self.zooming = False
        self.image_zoom = 0
        
    def get_zoom(self):
        # Use this function to retrieve the zoom_level
        zoom = abs(ml.dist(*self.finger_positions)) * 10
        return zoom if zoom > 1 else 1
    
    def event_handler(self, event):
        zoom_handler = self
        
        fingers = event.touch_gestures.fingers
        if event.mouse.press and "0" in fingers and "1" in fingers and event.touch_gestures.finger_count > 1:
            f1 = event.touch_gestures.fingers["0"].xy
            f2 = event.touch_gestures.fingers["1"].xy
            self.finger_positions = [f1, f2]
            self.zooming = True
        else:
            self.zooming = False
```